# KVM on Ryzen: Can the guest OS tell the difference vs. an Intel CPU?

Tags: virtualization, linux-kvm, amd-ryzen

Suppose I have an x86 operating system that was not developed with Ryzen CPUs in mind nor tested against them. Is there a good chance it will run in KVM on a Ryzen machine?

I'm guessing that AMD CPUs have slight differences in the instruction set vs. Intel, but most instructions should map one-to-one? That being the case, does KVM have the ability to emulate instructions that differ while simultaneously "passing through" instructions that are native to Zen?

Comment: I will rephrase the question to remove any reference to macOS.

Comment: KVM isn't going to care if you have a AMD or Intel CPU

Comment: "I'm guessing that AMD CPUs have slight differences in the instruction set vs. Intel" - They actually have the same x86 instruction set otherwise they wouldn't be x86 processors....Zen/Ryzen instructions wouldn't work on Intel, any program that used them, woudl simply crash just like Intel only extensions (i.e. AES extensions) woudln't work on AMD CPUs

Answer (score 0):

According to my investigations, Ryzen the Zen microarchitecture support the following instruction sets:

> x86-64, MMX, SSE1 through SSE4.2, AES, CLMUL, AVX, AVX2, FMA3, CVT16, F16C, ABM, BMI1, BMI2, SHA

Any app that has been compiled to take advantage of these instruction sets can use them.

As for being able to tell what CPU you are using, yes, it can... but only if it wanted to, i.e. if the developer inserted appropriate code. And let me tell, you such code is categorized as "arcana".